# undefined reference для Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector()

Tags: c++, poco, undefined-reference, conan

Библиотеки Poco ставились при помощи conan и cmake, IDE может перейти к коду библиотеки, но у линковщика с ней проблемы. Основные причины данной проблемы проверил, не помогло. Библиотека устанавливалась poco, должна подходить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Data/Session.h>
#include <Poco/Data/MySQL/Connector.h>



 int main(){
        Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector();
        Poco::Data::Session session{"MySQL", "host=localhost;port=3306;db=statsDB;user=user;password=pass"};
        return 0;
}
```

Для SQLite все работает хорошо, но если сменить в коде SQLite на MySQL, make не справляется. Текст ошибки:

```
   CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::Session::Session(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `Poco::Data::Session::~Session()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'ISPstats' failed
make[3]: *** [ISPstats] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'ISPstats' failed
make: *** [ISPstats] Error 2
```

после применения ответа @isnullxbh ругается так:

```
CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/nerd/CLionProjects/ISPstats/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'ISPstats' failed
make[2]: *** [ISPstats] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

а старая так:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoMongoDB
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoNet
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoNetSSL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoCrypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoData
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoDataSQLite
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoZip
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoUtil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoXML
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoJSON
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPocoFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'ISPstats' failed
make[2]: *** [ISPstats] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ISPstats.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: @VTT, обращаюсь к Вам, потому что Вы голосовали за закрытие вопроса: ответ, ссылка на который приведена в начале вопроса, никакого отношения к данному вопросу не имеет - автор вопроса сам понимает, с чем это связано, и ему нужно помочь с этим разобраться. Пересмотрите, пожалуйста, вопрос. Пишу здесь, потому что не знаю, как поступают в таких случаях, если это делается как-то инчае - извините, я не знал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того, как Вы выполните команду `conan install ...`, в исходной директории появится файл `conanbuildinfo.cmake` - так вот, Вам нужно подключить его через [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/include.html) в cmake-файле, например:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
```

Затем указать директории с установленными библиотеками:

```
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${CONAN_LIB_DIRS})
```

И слинковаться с ними:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

UPD.:

В секцию options добавьте строчку:

```
Poco:enable_data_mysql=True
```

Посмотреть список опций можно [здесь](https://github.com/pocoproject/conan-poco/blob/72b8134424e2249842d1802c5c47d104732f72c2/conanfile.py#L31).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92829/discussion-on-answer-by-isnullxbh-undefined-reference--pocodatamysqlcon).